# Set breakpoints into Object Pascal code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, delphi, omnipascal

```
I installed OmniPascal and Language Pascal extensions into VSCode. 
I have already installed FPC and GDB. 
I already compiled the Object Pascal code and have executable file created with the FPC. 
I can set breakpoints and debug C++ code within VSCode.
```

I can't set breakpoints into the Object Pascal code -> when clicking on the area on the left side of the line numbers, nothing happens => what should I do to be able to set the breakpoints into the Object Pascal code (and have the breakpoints used when debugging the file with GDB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these extensions have debug capabilities. According to [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/Wosi/omnipascalissues/issues/20/debug-abilities) reported in OmniPascal, you could try [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) as an *experimental way* to debug FreePascal.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Because I know that Lazarus debugs Object Pascal with GDB, I thought that there must be a way, how to do it. If that Native Debug is the only way how to debug native applications compiled with "-g" in compilers, I will use it.

Comment: Wow, it works for quite complex helloWorld! 
I will try the debugger for our real project now.

Comment: Btw, can I build .groupproj via FPC somehow? I asked there: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371464/building-delphi-project-from-visual-studio-code